# How can we refer to women we don't know

Tags: word-choice

How can we name female people whose name we dont know when we refer to them?

I was in a situation in which I talked to a female person who works at information desk in a company and after I talked to her , I talked to someone else in the same place.So in this situation how can we refer to the first person I talked to if we do not her name and she is about in middle-ages like 35.

Should I say:

1.The lady I talked to on reception desk said that..  (for me it sounds fancy)

2.The woman I talked to on reception desk said that.. (for me it sounds a bit rude )

3.The girl I talked to on reception desk said that..  ( for me it sounds unfitting)

4.The ma'am I talked to on reception desk said that..

5.Another option

I wrote what I feel for some options but I can be wrong.
Thank you

Comment: There is nothing rude about #2. I think it's your safest option.

Comment: "The woman 'at' the reception desk",(AmE) or "The woman 'in' reception," (as in 'reception area') -or- "The receptionist said..." (save yourself the social anxiety)

Comment: Do not use 'girl' to refer to grown woman.

Comment: If you don't like girl, you might wanna try 'guuuuuuurl'

Comment: You might say "she is middle aged" or "she is in middle age", but never "she is in the middle ages".  The middle ages is a period of history, not a period of one's life.

Comment: @David Wallace Thank you.So is it wrong too to say " she is in middle ages "

Comment: Well, it seems ungrammatical to me, but I can't put my finger on a precise rule that forbids it.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think the problem is that if you are "in an age" it refers to a historical age, not your personal age. It's the same word, but a different definition. It's "in my middle-aged years" not "in my middle ages". Does that make sense?

Comment: Is mentioning her gender necessary?  If not, I might go with "person", or "The receptionist I spoke to..."

Comment: I would use person, receptionist, or lady if it was important to mention gender. If the person was male, I am much more likely to use "dude", a bad habit, I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is generationally and regionally variable.  I am answering for the West Coast of the United States.

> 1.The lady I spoke with at the reception desk said that..

Feels slightly casual to my ears, but is frequently used.

> 2.The woman I spoke with at the reception desk said that..

In most cases I would chose this one.

> 3.The girl I spoke with at the reception desk said that..

Unless she is much, much younger than me (high school age), I would not say this.  People older than me - say 50-55 and up would say this with no disrespect intended, *even if the woman is their own age.*

> 4.The ma'am I spoke with at the reception desk said that..

I sometimes use *ma'am* when addressing women directly.  I would absolutely never refer to a woman in the third person as *a ma'am* or *the ma'am* unless she ran a brothel.  It sounds too much like *madam.*

> 5. The gal I spoke with at the reception desk said that..

This is common in the West, especially among people from rural areas.

So - In my region, #4 is one to categorically avoid.  #3 is only slightly better. You'll hear #5 used, but unless you have flawless English and can let it out in a lazy drawl, I would steer clear there too.  #1 isn't bad, and  **#2** is your best bet.

I will be curious to hear what people from other places say.

Comment: I mostly agree. "gal" is appropriate in certain regions, but sounds much more informal and would sound odd from someone who didn't seem to be "native" to the region. Lady seems possible again depending on region. It might sound old-fashioned in some places. 

Definitely avoid "the ma'ma". The girl is okay for children/women much younger than you.

Comment: People older than you can train or retrain themselves to *not* use 'girl'. I would not use the term in public, as it really is chauvinistic--and I believe most women object to it. Similarly, if a woman starts calling me 'honey' (because that is their habit when addressing men), I will tell them to their face to not call me that. Unless it's a cute nurse.

Comment: @carsmack.  Agreed - _girl_ needs to go.  In the 90's, my dad had a friend who called all women _sweetie,_ which drove my mom nuts until she found out his age.  He looked like he was 60, but was actually 85.  Once she knew his age, she gave him a bit of a pass, since for his generation it was such a common expression.

Comment: @Adam eques and CarSmack thank you. I learned a lot from your answers.I think I will stick to using the word woman.I don't why I thought it sounds  a bit rude.I think political correctness has gone mad for me. Because I wouldn't mind at all if somebody refers to me as a man simply.

Comment: @Murat: the main way "woman" could be rude, here in the UK at least, is to someone who thinks that you should always say "lady" and hence to say "woman" implies "not a lady", that is to say the person is somehow not respectable (and the same for saying "man" instead of "gentleman", if people who think that treat the sexes the same. Which they often don't!) But unless you create the contrast by saying, "the lady at reception and the ... *woman* ... in accounts" then it won't normally be taken that way.

Answer (score 5):

> 1.The lady I talked to on reception desk said that.. (for me it sounds fancy)

In my AmE dialect, this is what we typically use. "Lady" here is just polite and not intended to imply she is part of the Nobility or to [put on airs](http://www.idiomeanings.com/idioms/put-on-airs/). Lady can be used in less polite ways though ("Move it lady! The light's green!") so I would recommend the next sentence for general purpose use:

> 2.The woman I talked to on reception desk said that.. (for me it sounds a bit rude )

Woman is the most neutral and widely accepted word to use in this context, in my opinion. If you said "The female at the desk" it would imply either that you have an unfavorable opinion of her or that you don't know the correct term in English, but woman is neutral.

> 3.The girl I talked to on reception desk said that.. ( for me it sounds unfitting)

I would probably not refer to woman working in a customer service position as a girl unless she was obviously under 19 or so (in high school, not college). Usually high school girls are not working as receptionists, so in this context I wouldn't use it. An example where I would use girl is "the checkout girl at the market". Many high school aged girls work as cashiers at our market, and they are too young to be referred to as women.

> 4.The ma'am I talked to on reception desk said that..

I would never use ma'am in this way. In the Southern US, we often say "Thank you, ma'am!" or "Thank you, sir!" to customer service people regardless of their age, but I would never use "The ma'am" to refer to a woman.

I personally would say:

> The lady I spoke to **at the** reception desk said...

or

> The woman I spoke to **at the** reception desk said...

Answer (score 3):

Since you are referring to a more formal or professional setting, I would use your second option:

> The woman I talked to at the reception desk said...

Or:

> The receptionist said...

Which might be better because gendered titles (stewardess, waitress, actress, saleswoman) are falling out of favor in America (for gender equality reasons), so I would prefer a gender-neutral term unless necessary.

And I agree with other answers regarding #3, never use girl to refer to a grown woman (18+).

*(Note that I grew up on the west coast of the United States.)*

Answer (score 0):

Regionalism does play a part. In the South and parts of the Southwest, many people of varying ages would say "the lady", or call her "ma'am," even if she were considerably younger. The exception would be if they were being casual or cutesy, where a woman might call another woman a "girl" or "gal" in a friendly manner. It took me the better part of ten years to get used to that habit. I grew up in the Midwest, where we would use the term "woman", and my experience in places like California, Boston, New York, etc., is that it's common currency there too.

You may also refer to her as "The person who I spoke to" - independent of gender. If you continued speaking you'd probably refer to either she or he (e.g. "The person I spoke to was very patient with me. She told me where I could go to find the right paperwork I needed.")

Someone reiterated that you should not call a grown woman a "girl" in any professional context. This is true, unless you have an established friendship in a casual setting where she has already used similar language (for instance, an off-the-clock meeting with a group of colleagues at the bar). I would say overall, avoid.

Likewise, never make assumptions about a woman's marriage status, and avoid using terms that designate marriage status for a stranger, unless she tells you specifically to use it. It is always OK to call a woman in business or professional settings, "Ms." (Pronounced "Mizz") because it can be used regardless of whether she is married, or not. It's been used for hundreds of years but became more recently popular. "Miss" and "Mrs." designate marriage status.

About ten to fifteen percent of women in the US keep their name after marriage, as I did, which is another reason why Ms. is a better catch-all title. "Ms. Tail-Kinker" has been correct my entire life. It is incorrect when people call me "Mrs. Tail-Kinker", though, even though I am married. Tail-Kinker is my surname or "maiden" name, the one I got from my father's side of the family. In *Spanish speaking* cultures I believe it is typical for a woman to be called "Mrs. Tail-Kinker" after she marries, rather than "Mrs. [Husband's name]". But in US practice, the term Mrs. refers to a woman using her husband's name, not her maiden name. If you therefore call a woman who has kept her original name "Mrs. Original Name", she might be offended or annoyed. Many of us particularly find it extremely rude to refer to a married woman as "Mrs. Husband's First Name - Husband's Last Name".

Again, the safe bet professionally is to call someone "Ms." and then follow whatever they ask you to do specifically.

Comment: I believe that almost all native speakers mean something different by "Christian name" from what they mean by "maiden name".

Comment: I still don't find "surname" and "maiden name" to be synonymous.  My wife's surname is Wallace.  Her maiden name isn't.

Comment: I do think that the terminology is lacking when it comes to the married woman's surname situation. Surname means your last name from wherever it may have come, maiden name means your surname prior to you changing your name after getting married, and married name means the name you changed your surname to after getting married. If you didn't change your surname, you have neither a maiden nor a married name in my dialect, just a surname.

Comment: Oh but then there's that rare-but-it's-happened situation where the husband takes the wife's surname - does he have a "maiden" name? Best just to skip changing a woman's title because she's married and use Ms. similar to the way Mr. can mean a married or unmarried man and just call them all surnames :)

Comment: I did not say that surname and maiden name are synonymous. I specified first that **I** did not change my surname upon marriage. I then stated that **my** surname is also what is called a "maiden name", the name I was given by my parents.

Comment: I know couples where the man took the woman's name; the woman kept her name, but the children received hyphenated names, similar to the Spanish tradition; where the woman hyphenated her name, but the children have the husband's family name; where both the husband and the wife have the same hyphenated family names (hername-hisname, hisname-hername), and even where the husband and wife took on a completely new surname. Now, it's pretty simple with a man in any scenario above - you call him Mr. WhateverHeWantstoBeCalled. The safe bet is to also call a woman Ms. WhateverSheWantstoBeCalled.

Comment: For our next exercise, we can discuss the character of Mrs Joe in Great Expectations :-)

Comment: Not to pick nits, but "maiden name" is not the name you were given by your parents; that's just your surname. Because you didn't change your name when you married, you don't have a maiden name. If you have been married more than once, and you changed your name the first time, is "maiden name" always the name given by your parents? I don't think so, but I'm not sure. The terminology around women changing their surnames in the modern era is interesting and I'm curious now about how different dialects handle it. I'm going to go search ELU and see if the question has been asked yet.

Comment: @ColleenV: here in the UK we do say that someone "kept her maiden name". But if someone's never been married and is asked "what's your maiden name?" she'd respond "eh? What are you on about?", she wouldn't just say her surname. So I suppose a "maiden name" here is the surname before marriage of a married woman, regardless of whether she changes it on marriage. When people ask as a security question "what's your mother's maiden name?", they're kind of assuming your mother is/was married so that she has one. And it's an especially bad secret if she still uses it.

Comment: ... still worse if the son/daughter does too.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think the gender/wedlock neutral term some have settled on is "birth name". It seems more sensible to me than maiden name :) I have noticed the mother's maiden name security question is falling out of favor.

Comment: @ColleenV: maybe a good general term, although since I don't commonly use/encounter that term "birth name" it just raises more questions for me. What if I was born with one name but later in childhood took a step-parent's name? Born with my father's name and later legally changed to mother's? Then what's my birth name? I'd have no trouble saying that my (well, not literally my) maiden name in both cases is the name I switched to, not the one I was born with. If someone needs "name on birth certificate" they can say so. And so on with the quibbling ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about the person at the desk? Personally I use the term ma'am. I was raised to be respectful. Women you do not know,and are unaware of their social status(married,simngle) you address as ma'am,men as sir. If you know them it is Ms. Miss or Mrs. then their last name,unless you have PERMISSION from them to use their given name.
Ma'am is not an insult,it is a sign of courtesy and respect.
So those women who get upset over it,I suggest you get over yourself MA'AM!!

Comment: Welcome to ELL Jake! I'm not sure this answers the question. Murat is not asking about how to _address_ a woman he doesn't know but rather how to _refer_ to her. "The ma'am at the desk" isn't common in any dialect that I'm familiar with.